# Final layout rendering is animated while tableview is presented

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am using the tableview in a custom developed UI control.
The default frame of my tableView is {0,0,0,0}..So it's not visible..I am using the UIview's animation class methods with blocks (animateWithDuration:delay:..etc..) to animate this tableview "into the screen".The animation block contains only the frame.size change to {0,0, 320, 250}. So obviously, a few cells become visible as the frame of tableview is changed.

Further, I have a custom UIView with four UILabels in it. The labels are snapping to the bottom.
In cellForRowAtIndexPath: I am adding this custom view to the cell's content view and I resize this custom view to match the content view frame.

```
customView.frame = cell.frame;
[cell.contentView addSubview:customView];
```

My problem is, as the cell's have different height, (resolved in heightForRowAtIndexPath)...
the particular Custom view in particular cell is changing its frame, effectively moving the labels vertically down by a few pixels, during the main animation.

I want them to be in their place already when I am presenting the tableview.~

How to achieve this?

Comment: [autoresizingMask](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask)

Comment: What kind of visual effect are you going for here? It sounds lily you might want more if a sliding-into-place effect (its contents stay in place relative to the moving view), not growing-into-place (contents have to start at zero size and stretch). If that's the case, maybe your table should keep its *size* constant and animate its *position* starting from somewhere offscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use autoresizingMask property of the cells, or:

You can create a custom table view cell, add those views, and handle that in the layoutSubviews of the cell.

Comment: I want the labels to be NOT animated into their final place. I want them to be ALREADY there, when the animation of main table view happens. So the question is not about layout rules, but why the label are moved to their final place in animated manner and how to have this layouting inside the cell not animated.

Comment: You have two options to solve that - as I said-> layoutSubviews can help you avoid animating them by giving them fixed size and position.
The second option, is to wait for the animation to end, and only then add them. (Just put a flag and in the end of the animation reloadData again or something).

The views are animating to their final position because if you change the frame of the table in animation, all the layoutSubivews inside those cells and inside the tableView is animating as well. To avoid that you need to somehow override the layoutSubviews or to add them in the end.

Comment: I moved the respective code to layoutSubviews, it helped, no animation happens now, thanks.